# Problemas a la hora de aplicar aleatorios

Tags: java, random, match

Hola el Aleatorio que arme me sale un error "Fuera de banda" no se como resolverlo, seguro esta mal armado. muchas gracias.

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GoogleNum {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner leer = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n ;
    int buscado;
    System.out.println("Ingrese la dimension del vector");
    n = leer.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Ingrese el numero que desea buscar en el vector");
    buscado = leer.nextInt();

    int i;
    Random aleatorio = new Random();
    int [] VectorEnteros = new int[0];
    for( i = 0 ; i < n ; i++){
        VectorEnteros[i] = aleatorio.nextInt(10);//me sale error en esta linea
    }

    int cont = 0;
    for( i = 0 ; i < n ; i++){

        if(VectorEnteros[i] == buscado){

            cont = cont + 1;
            System.out.println("Se encontro una coincidencia con el valor buscado [" + buscado + "] en la posicion " + i + " del vector.");

        }

    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bienvenido Diego
Te encuentras obteniendo aquel error debido a que estás declarando la variable `VectorEnteros` con un tamaño 0, haciendo que el código no funcione al momento de recorrer el array para llenarlo con números aleatorios (Ya que no hay espacio alguno para introducir datos). Asígnale el tamaño `n` introducido por el usuario y ya debería de funcionar:

```
int[] VectorEnteros = new int[n];
```

Answer (score 3):

El vector esta inicializado con 0 elementos:

```
int [] VectorEnteros = new int[0];
```

Al tratar de iterar y buscar un elemento en el vector obtendrás un error "Index 0 out of bounds for length 0", ya que no tiene elementos.

Cuando obtienes la dimensión del vector, esta se guarda en la variable `n`, esta variable debes usarla para dimensionar el vector.

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner leer = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n ;
        int buscado;
        System.out.println("Ingrese la dimension del vector");
        n = leer.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Ingrese el numero que desea buscar en el vector");
        buscado = leer.nextInt();

        int i = 0;
        Random aleatorio = new Random();
        int [] VectorEnteros = new int[n]; //* inicializa vector.
        for(i = 0 ; i < n ; i++){
            VectorEnteros[i] = aleatorio.nextInt(10);
        }

        System.out.println("valores en VectorEnteros : " + Arrays.toString(VectorEnteros));
        
        int cont = 0;
        for( i = 0 ; i < n ; i++){

            if(VectorEnteros[i] == buscado){

                cont = cont + 1;
                System.out.println("Se encontro una coincidencia con el valor buscado [" + buscado + "] en la posicion " + i + " del vector.");

            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: mil gracias, se resolvio el codigo y aprendi algo nuevo.